# unable to debug hybrid application on android 4.3

Tags: android, webview, appcelerator, remote-debugging, web-inspector

I am developing a hybrid application using Appcelerator Titanium
by following [this link](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging), I am able to debug my website using chrome on mobile, but i need to debug my hybrid application on android 4.3 or at least debug on the native browser.
thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can debug the application in the standard titanium IDE.

[Here is a link for using the Titanium IDE](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Debugging_on_the_Emulator_or_Simulator-section-35225628_DebuggingontheEmulatororSimulator-ToDebugonAndroidEmulatororiOSSimulator)

[Here is a video using Titanium IDE](http://vimeo.com/21949107)

[Here is a video doing it with Chrome Tools](http://vimeo.com/70244213)

Comment: thank you for replying, my problem is that i am using the native browser (web view) so i am trying to debug the html controls in the web view not the webview as a control, i am able to do this for android 4.4+ but i need to debug on 4.3.